# Notice: undefine index:email error in PHP session

Tags: php, session

I keep getting this error even though I checked my code over dozens of times.

Here I even define **SESSION** on top as global before using but I keep getting the same error.

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}  ?>
```

Then I use this line of code

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);?>
```

It removes the `Notice: Undefined index:email` error but the email column remains in blank in the database whenever I insert the data.

It says error on this lines of coding.

```
$s="insert into donation(ddate,units,detail,email) values('" . $d ."' ,'" . $_POST["t3"]
     . "','" . $_POST["t4"] . "','". $_SESSION["email"] ."')";
```

Comment: The problem isn't `$_SESSION`, it's that the index 'email' doesn't exist on `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Even if you suppress the error report the error is still there. You're trying to access an index that doesn't exist. I think we need more code than this to help you. Where and how do you set the value for $_SESSION['email']

Comment: Where you set `email` in the session? Can you show that code.

Answer (score 0):

try to echo ur session value so u can know u get session value or not...

after session_start();

echo $_SESSION['email'];

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `session_start();` before applying conditions with $_SESSION.
Your code should be :

```
<?php session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION)) { //DO SOMETHING HERE } 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);

 $s="insert into donation(ddate,units,detail,email) values('" . $d ."' ,'" . 
 $_POST["t3"]
 . "','" . $_POST["t4"] . "','". $_SESSION["email"] ."')";
 ?>
```